# Jquery event .live not working on 1.4.2?

Tags: jquery

It looks like .live() not working on version 1.4.2 anymore. Is it true?

Comment: I doubt it.  Can you make your question more specific?

Comment: It would help if you post a code where it fails.

Answer (score 0):

[`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) works in 1.4.2+, though there is a specific issue with IE8 and the `change` event bubbling (you can use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) however).  Is that your issue?

There are no other issues with [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) I'm aware of, if you provided more context it would help discern the exact issue, given it's not IE8 & `change` like I mention above.

Answer (score 0):

Not true.

Here's [proof](http://jsfiddle.net/XaycU/). I've selected jQuery 1.4.2 on the left.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem using jQuery 1.4.2 as described here [jQuery UI ajax tabs - requests multiplying when loading links within tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588423/jquery-ui-ajax-tabs-requests-multiplying-when-loading-links-within-tabs)

In 1.4.2. live() didn't work as expected and it didn't cause requests multiplying if you don't use .die() to prevent .live() from being defined multiple times.