# jQuery UI ajax tabs - requests multiplying when loading links within tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using jQuery UI tabs, loading the tab content via ajax. Content may contain links which I want to load within the selected tab. To achieve that, I use this code

```
$("#tab-div").tabs({  
    load: function(event, ui) {
    $('a:not('.targetBlank'), ui.panel).live('click', function() {
        $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

I use live() so that the links loaded after the initial load are also covered.

Now, imagine a situation where you have 2 tabs. First, the user is in tab_a, which contains links. The user clicks a link within tab_a and it opens fine. Then, tab_b is selected, then tab_a, and the link within again.

so that's: tab_a -> link within -> tab_b -> tab_a -> link within

Now after tab_a is selected for the second time, and the link within after that, I get two requests when link is clicked. If I repeat the process, once I click on link within tab_a, I'll get three requests and so on.

I can't quite get the grip on what's going on in here.

.targetBlank class is for links that are not intended to open within a tab. It's not particularly relevant, but I thought I'd share it as well, if it turns out to be important somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a flag if the content has already been bound, or unbind the content on tab change.

Something like `ui.panel.find('a').unbind()` should do the trick. Make sure you put it in the tab change callback.

Comment: This problem happens when I use jquery ui 1.8.7 with jquery 1.4.4. When I use it with 1.4.2 everything's fine, requests don't multiply. I've filed a ticket at jquery ui ticket tracker http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6802